# What is the hottest filament I could find in an incandescent lamp?

Tags: incandescent

I read old light bulbs get really hot.

I read that the incandescent lamps get quite hot but I couldn’t find a filament that gets ‘the hottest’.

Is there a filament that gets the hottest?

Comment: The shortest lived one. So, probably magnesium photo flash bulbs ... lifetime is measured in milliseconds (and I haven't seen new ones since the 1970s)

Comment: All filaments for incandescent bulbs are effectively pure tungsten since the 1910’s, so no difference there. The bulb glass diameter will determine how how to the touch it will be, for a given power.

Comment: Look up “Exploding wire method” in wikipedia. The wire won’t survive, but it gets really hot before becoming plasma! I had a colleague who did exploding wire spectroscopy.

Comment: If you count ionised gasses as a "filament", then arc lamps would be the hottest :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of "what kind of sugar candy is best for the roof of my house?" None!  If your goal is to make heat, incandescent is your worst possible choice.  A resistive heating element (that **isn't** trying to make light) will perform for a lifetime if built properly. Look at any $35-50 Cadet baseboard heater in a house.  And if you want light, you know what to do.

Comment: There are different grades of heat. A baseboard heater is making low grade heat.

Answer (score 12):

In commercial bulbs run at recommended voltage, you can still get [photoflood bulbs](https://www.bulbamerica.com/products/osram-sylvania-500w-120v-ebv-ps25-super-photoflood-incandescent-light-bulb) which draw 500W and have a color temperature of 3400K, which, in an incandescent bulb (without color filter) is also the temperature of the filament (3125°C),

Lifetime is rated at only 8 hours, so there is a direct trade-off for the higher filament temperature and resulting whiter light (the filament has a smooth [black-body radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation) spectrum).

Answer (score 8):

The hotter the filament, the whiter the light, and the more efficiently it will run. Tungsten halogen bulbs run somewhat hotter and more efficiently than GLS bulbs, and so have replaced them on the market where a filament is still required.

The lifetime of a filament bulb is strongly related to its running temperature. In the GLS type bulb, it typically varies inversely as the 14th power of the applied voltage. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamp_rerating) wikipedia entry on Lamp Rerating gives the following relationships

- lifetime \$V^{-12}\$ to \$V^{-16}\$
- colour temperature \$V^{0.42}\$
- luminous intensity \$V^{3.4}\$ to \$V^{3.5}\$

If you are doing a brief experiment and have no need for bulb longevity, you can increase the applied power and increase the filament temperature. You would need to sacrifice a few bulbs to verify the lifetime at your required colour temperature

You can estimate the filament temperature from the ratio of its resistance when running, to resistance when cold, using published tables of temperature coefficient of resistance for tungsten.

The melting point of tungsten is 3695 K, so @Sphero's identification of a lamp that runs at 3400 K and is rated to last 8 hours represents about the best you are going to get commercially.

The way the halogen cycle works to prolong filament life means that a proper high temperature 'photo flood' light will last longer than a standard tungsten halogen overrun to the same temperature. This is because the manufacturer would have added more halogen to the envelope, anticipating the higher filament boil-off rate at higher temperature. In the standard bulb, the halogen filling will become overwhelmed at the higher temperature, and fail to recycle the filament.

Comment: What’s GLS please? And how would I get it to ‘white’ hot rather than ‘red’ hot please?

Comment: @Benjamin How to get to white hot? You increase the applied power. How much extra power? Increase it until the filament burns out, then back off a bit.

Comment: @Benjamin, "GLS" is a fancy name for a standard incandescent bulb.

Comment: GLS = general lighting service.